# presentation and usage of functionality at runtime

Tags: c++, dynamic, interface, pointer-to-member

I want to present a class's functionalities(member functions) to outside world without exposing it's functions in it's public section. so the user will be able to know/invoke it's functions dynamically. Here are some methods:
a) Provide pointers to member functions. pointers which are served in structs with an accompanying string to hold the name of the function.

```
class IBase
{
public:      
  typedef void (IBase::*FuncPtr)(Iparameter*);  
  typedef struct Module
  {
     FuncPtr Func;
     string Name; 
  };
  vector<Module> GetFunctions()const
  {  
    vector<Module> vec;  
    vec.push_back(Module(&F1, "F1"));  
    vec.push_back(Module(&F2,"F2"));  
    return vec;  
  }
private:  
  void F1(IParameter *param){}  
  void F2(IParameter *param){}  
};
```

b) Provide a string list of function names, plus, a function taking a string parameter to invoke specified member function.

```
class IBase
{
public:
  void Invoke(string funcName, IParameter *param)
  {
   if(funcName=="F1")F1(param);
   else if(funcName=="F2")F2(param);
  }
private:  
  void F1(IParameter *param){}  
  void F2(IParameter *param){}
};
```

**Question:** which method is more efficient? are there any better approaches? am I re-inventing the wheel(boost::function? )?

**Notes:**
* IParameter is such a class that is, designed to hold generic/self-explanatory data and each function knows how to interpret it.
* All functions' signature are the same:

```
void FuncName(IParameter*);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, quicker than linearly searching through a vector or a series of `if-else` would be to use e.g. a `std::map` (*O(log N)* lookup time), or a `std::hash_map` (*O(1)* lookup time typically).

But the real question is: why do you want to access functions by name (i.e. with a string) at run-time?  Surely an index or a pointer would be easier?  In other words, why is the first argument to your `Invoke()` function a string?

Comment: Since the member functions will be shown in a GUI, I have to export them with a string(function's name). But the Invoke function does not need to take the information about which function to call in a string, surely it can use an indice.

Comment: @Taz: I understand that.  But providing a string for human-readable purposes does not mean that you need to perform lookups in your data structure with that string.